# Android_Home issue on MAC

Tags: c#, macos, selenium, appium

I have set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable on my MAC but still getting an error says:

```
The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb.[ADB] Error: Could not find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.
```

I have used the following commands in the Mac's terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ seleniumMac$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/seleniumMX/Library/Android/sdk
MacBook-Pro:~ seleniumMac$ export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
MacBook-Pro:~ seleniumMac$ export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
MacBook-Pro:~ seleniumMac$ export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```

Comment: Add them in the vi ~/.bash_profile and after that run source ~/.bash_profile , this should probably solve. Let me know if you still face an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands after installing brew

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

and install android-sdk using

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

Now copy the below to your `./bash_profile` and save/source it.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal!

Comment: so you think I should uninstall the android sdk and re-install it with brew? I have installed it as an application with installation file

Comment: If you are using a mac machine, yes! this is the best option!

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check @YanivEliav